# How to send a form/notification to user from a DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, dll, dllimport, toast

I have a DLL .
And want to send a form/notification to user( who would reference my dll) from this dll.

I just want to build a function inside one class in my dll such that ->, once a user runs his local program and references my dll -> and calls a function that is present in dll  -> that particular function should show up a form/notification to user ( from some functionalities in dll )? Is there any other method for the same?

I tried converting the library to a Winform from class library type and that would change its properties into an executable and it would demand presence of the main function. But I am just building a library that can be referenced and when called by the user produces a form at their end?

I tried toast notifications but not .show() method doesnt work inside new ToastContentBuilder() while i call that in a fucntion from my library . Otherwise as an idenpendant console app , it worked fine

---

Is there a way I can have a project for toast notification in the same solution as that of my library and then call from a class in my main library -> the function present in this different project for toast notif and would produce the toast notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following steps to send a notification to the user from the dll.

**First**, please create a class library(Target Framework is **.NET Core 3.1**) called `TestDll`.

**Second**, you could install the nuget-package `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` in the class library.

**Third**, you can add a class and refer to the following code example.

```
namespace TestDll
{
    public class Example
    {
        public void Setnotifications()
        {
            new ToastContentBuilder().AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
.AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
.AddText("Ev2 Compiler Library")
.AddText("Allow sending build Data to Microsoft")
.AddButton(new ToastButton()
    .SetContent("Yes")
    .AddArgument("action", "reply")
    .SetBackgroundActivation())
    .AddButton(new ToastButton()
    .SetContent("No")
    .AddArgument("action", "like")
    .SetBackgroundActivation())
.SetToastScenario(ToastScenario.Reminder)
.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, please rebuild the class lib and create a console app(Target Framework is .NET Core 3.1).

Fifth, we can add the project reference TestDll to the console app and write the following example in the main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example example = new Example();
            example.Setnotifications();

        }
```

**Finally**, we can see the notification in the right bottom of computer like the following:

[image]

**Besides**, the problem about 'toast notifications but not .show() method' maybe that you used **.net standard** framework, you can solve the problem by changing to the **.net core** framwork.

Comment: wait ! I did the toast notification thing and wrote the exact same thing on my toast . Where did you get the image of this toast notif or you built on own ?? Is this a jinx ??

Comment: @plsHELP, I get the image from the right bottom of the screen after I run the app. What is your current problem?

Comment: AddText("Ev2 Compiler Library")
. This part - actually I wrote this is my Code with reference to my project. Seeing the same text here shocked me . Hence , I wanted to know the source of this line. Currently my whole library is in .net framework and the .cspproj doesn't mention it , its just showing in dependencies / Hence , I was confused on how to change . I changes the target framework to .net core 3.1 in .csproj file but still I get errors about .net standard and it doesn't go away from dependencies section

Comment: @plsHELP, based on my further test, after I change the target framework to  .net core 3.1, there is no errors for me. Have you rebuilt the project? If it still doesn't work, another way to solve the problem is to create a console app(.net core 3.1) directly instead of changing target-framework.

Comment: ON REFERECING TO .NET CORE 3.1 IT THROWS THIS ERROR : Project '..\Ev2\Ev2.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp3.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.  The library is having dependency on .net standard in the dependency files

Comment: @plsHELP, please remove all the reference related to .NETStandard.